# session update in codeigniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

hi i would like to ask if it is possible to update the session data saved in the database in codeigniter,, for example. i have a session userdata(roleID,name,logged_in), so that when someone will login, ill just call the `$data['name'] = $this->session->userdata('name');` and echo it in my header view as `<?php echo $name; ?>`,, the problem is when a user will update his firstname or lastname, and when i do this

```
$fname = $this->input->post('fname');
$lname = $this->input->post('lname');

$fullname = $fname." ".$lname;
$this->session->unset_userdata('name');
$this->session->set_userdata('name',$fullname);
```

it doesnt work..

**//EDIT**
WORKING RIGHT NOW... JUST TYPO AND SYNTAX ERRROR

Comment: that second unset should read set_ right ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to update the session data, use:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('name', $fullname);
```

There is no need to use `unset_userdata` 
More info [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't redeclare session again, just use the code:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('session_variable_name', $newvalue);
```

Example:

New session declaration:

```
$this->session->set_userdata(
               array(
               'year'  =>  2017
                ));
```

Updating current session value 'year' into '2018':

```
$this->session->set_userdata('year', 2018);
```