# how to update a new session in multidimensional array in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session, multidimensional-array

this is my session which will be show by `$order_id`

```
["items_250"]=>
array(4) {
["menu_0"]=>
array(4) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(3) " 86"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "231"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["choice"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
["menu_1"]=>
array(4) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(3) " 86"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "236"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["choice"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
["menu_2"]=>
array(4) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(3) " 86"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "232"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["choice"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
["menu_3"]=>
array(4) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(3) " 86"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "357"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["choice"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
}
```

i want if i used another `$oder_id` it will show only the session by the `$order_id`, example my first `order_id` is `86`, it will showed as the first session on top,

than if i used new `$order_id` example `83`, it will show :

```
["items_250"]=>
array(4) {
["menu_0"]=>
array(4) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(2) "83"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "236"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["choice"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
["menu_1"]=>
array(4) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(2) "83"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "357"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["choice"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

but if i used another `$order_id`

it will be showed this :

```
["items_250"]=>
array(4) {
["menu_0"]=>
array(4) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(2) "83"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "236"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["choice"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
["menu_1"]=>
array(4) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(2) "83"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "357"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["choice"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
["menu_2"]=>
array(4) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(3) " 86"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "232"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["choice"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
["menu_3"]=>
array(4) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(3) " 86"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "357"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["choice"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
}
```

as you can see from new session, the session of `user_order_id` are different, but it still showed the last session of `user_order_id`

this is how i set my session:

```
if($order_id !== $this->session->userdata('user_order_id')) {
    $count = count($menu_id); // get count
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $_SESSION['items_' . $restaurant_id]['menu_' . $i] = array(
                'user_order_id' => $order_id,
                'menu_id' => $menu_id[$i],
                'qty' => $qty[$i],
                "choice" => array($variant_name[$i]['variant_menu_id']),
                );
            }
    }else{

}
```

guys can you help me how to update the session?

Comment: what is your expected outcome?what you actually want to achieve? Your question is unclear for me at least.

Comment: @Anant which question is unclear?, at least i have said in the tittle of this question? i want trying to update a new session

Comment: Try it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133256/session-update-in-codeigniter